# Access 2010 VBA Filter --> How to display the filter string in a report textbox/label

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a Continuous Form which has multiple filters in the header, which then apply at the click of a button, and filter the table beneath. 
The user can then click a 'Report' Button which will put the results of that filter into a Report style, print-out friendly. 
I was wondering whether there was a way to return the filter applied, as a text box or label in my report?

FYI, the code is:

```
Private Sub frm_Filter_Click()
Dim strWhere As String
Dim lngLen As Long

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbCategory) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Category] = """ & Me.cmbCategory & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbStage) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Stage] = """ & Me.cmbStage & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbImpact) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Impact] = """ & Me.cmbImpact & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbStatus) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Status] = """ & Me.cmbStatus & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbOwner) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([Owner] = """ & Me.cmbOwner & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.cmbChangeType) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([ChangeType] = """ & Me.cmbChangeType & """) AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtOBR) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([tbl_Main.OBR] Like ""*" & Me.txtOBR & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtRaisedBy) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([tbl_Main.RaisedBy] Like ""*" & Me.txtRaisedBy & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtApplication) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & "([tbl_Main.Application] Like ""*" & Me.txtApplication & "*"") AND "
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Then
strWhere = strWhere & "(tbl_Main.Description Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' OR tbl_Main.LessonsLearnt Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*' OR tbl_Main.RecommendedAction Like '*" & Me.txtSearch & "*') AND "
End If

lngLen = Len(strWhere) - 5
If lngLen <= 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Criteria Selected", vbInformation, "Nothing to do."
Else
        strWhere = Left$(strWhere, lngLen)

        Me.Filter = strWhere
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it dynamically by referencing a textbox or label in your form

Add a label (`lblFilter`) to your report with Caption = "Filter Here"

Add a label (`lblFilter`) to your form header (make `Visible = False`) - same caption

Right after your line

```
Me.Filter = strWhere
```

Add the line to fill your invisible label

```
lblFilter.Caption = strWhere
```

Then in your Report_Open event add the code:

```
Me.lblFilter.Caption = Forms("MyFormName").lblFilter.Caption
```

Comment: Hi, In the "MyFormName" - This is the form containing the label? If so, It's coming up with an error saying it 'cannot find the referenced form'. My Forms are as follows: frm_EditLesson, frm_Main, frm_Edit, Navigation Form. The Navigation form contains the other 3 forms, I've also tried plugging the Nav form in, but get the same error.

Comment: If I try to open the form by itsself, without the Navigation form and run the report, I get the error: "Object doesn't support this Property or Method"

Comment: Which form "*has multiple filters in the header*" and which form has the button to open the report - and did you put the Label in the same header as the button and filter text boxes

Comment: frm_Main has multiple fields in the header, as well as the button to open the report. Yes I have put the Label in the same header as the button and filter text boxes.

Comment: Change your Report_Open line of code to say `Me.lblFilter.Caption = Forms("MyFormName").lblFilter.Caption` - you need to specify the .Caption property for labels

Comment: Thanks alot, I had the line in the Report_Load instead of Open. It's now displaying the filter in the label.
Instead of the actual text appearing however it is returning a number (the ID/Primary Key of the field?) Do you know how I can get it to return the value of the second column instead?

Comment: Use the .`Column` property of the combobox (assuming that's what your referring to). **NOTE** it's a zero-based index so you'll need to subtract one from your actual column location number.